# Retarget animation from Mixamo to Custom Rig upper arm is bent because has additional bone (UE 5.3)

Tags: unreal-engine5, mixamo, retargeting

I have a character with a custom rig. I downloaded a mixamo animation with its mixamo rig. I've done the retargeting. The animation on my custom rig looks very close. However, my custom rig has 2 bones in the upper arm where mixamo has 1, and it looks like this causes my custom character's upper arm to bend as a result. (The same happens on the thigh, but was more clear on screenshot on upper arm.)

Screenshot

- mixamo on left (gray)
- has one bone from deltoid to elbow
- custom rig character on right (skin material)
- selected to show has bone from deltoid to mid-upper arm, and second bone from mid to elbow

Is there a way to correct this? I tried some rotations of Edit Pose, it helped al ittle, but seems like there should be an easier way.

[image]